# gtk-window-decorator takes up too much memory, and is it safe to restart it?

Tags: gtk, window-decorations

I would like to restart the `gtk-window-decorator` process, because it takes up 600MB memory. Will that affect other processes? From my experiences, after killing it, all other programs will lose their window  frames, but after I run it again, the other programs will have their window frames back, and the `gtk-window-decorator` process will take much less memory.

If I rerun it in a shell session in background, I will kill it if I forget about it and accidentally close the shell session. How can I run it like the OS does?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks.

Comment: Is that 600MB VIRT or RSS?  There's a significant difference: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64964/how-to-interpret-this-top-command/64969#64969 and it's most likely the former, in which case it isn't really using that much and you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Top shows 114m  36m  13m for VIRT  RES  SHR respectively, and System monitor shows 563MiB for X Server memory, and almost 600MiB for "Memory". What relations are between these memories?

Comment: As per the link, virtual address space (the VIRT score) is not real memory; the best common metric for actual RAM used is "residential set size" (the RES score).  So 36 MB is not so bad.  When in doubt, trust tools that report both these numbers, as opposed to something which gives you an ambiguous "Memory" total.

Comment: Thanks. What is "X Server memory" that gtk-window-decorator takes up so much?

Comment: It could be a total for various things that are part of the GUI.  There's probably a process `X` which takes a good 100 or so MB RES.  If you press capital `F` in `top`, select `RES` (via arrows), then `s` to set this as the sort criteria and `Esc` to return to the normal view, the biggest consumers of memory will be kept at the top.  This will probably include a browser and various GUI bits and pieces (the DE executable, etc).  That should give you an idea of what's actually using what.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's an ugly bug, but no, there is no danger. As you said, this is just the window decorator, you can kill it and run it again and everything is fine.

As for running it, you can probably just run

```
gtk-window-decorator &
```

And then exit the terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or typing `exit`. Just don't close by clicking on the `X`.

Alternatively, you could run it with `nohup`:

```
nohup gtk-window-decorator &
```

Or launch normally and disown the process:

```
$ gtk-window-decorator &
[1234]
$ disown 1234
```

Here, the `1234` is the PID of the backgrounded process, the actual number will be different on your system.

Comment: System Monitor provides two options to terminate the process: "kill the process" and "end the process".  From command line, how do you do those respectively? Which one is better?

Comment: It depends, and that it a whole different question. You might want to have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/436392/85695) for a list of the different signals. My guess is that "Terminate" sends a `SIGTERM` while "kill" sends `SIGKILL` but the details depend on how the system monitor is implemented. Anyway, from the commandline, just run `killall gtk-window-decorator`.